# How can I force my desktop browser to never use mobile Wikipedia links (e.g., en.m.wikipedia.org)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, mobile-url

Often in the comments of a website someone will post a mobile Wikipedia link (e.g., https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), presumably because their mobile browser sent them there and they copy-pasted the link.

Is there a browser extension or other solution that will convert the explicit `en.m.wikipedia.org` mobile link to `en.wikipedia.org`?

---

For my use case this specifically applies to Firefox (version 62.0a1 (2018-05-11) (64-bit) at the time of writing).  However, I also often use Chrome as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may use the Redirector add-on, available on
[Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/)
and
[Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirector/pajiegeliagebegjdhebejdlknciafen):

> This simple extension allows you to redirect urls using the power of regular expressions.
>
> For example, you can have all mobile Wikipedia urls to open in desktop mode (this is convered in the tutorial below).

For documentation, visit the product [home page](http://bendavis78.github.io/chrome-extension-redirector) for a tutorial with this example :

> To set up a redirect for mobile Wikipedia urls, enter the following:

```
From: ^http:\/\/(.*?)\.m\.wikipedia\.org\/(.*) 
To: http://$1.wikipedia.org/$2
```

---

As another possibility, you could also use the Firefox add-on
[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/),
available on Chrome under the name of
[Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).

You could use this
[Greasemonkey script which redirects Wikipedia mobile to the desktop version](https://ktpanda.org/monkey/wikipedia_desktop_redirect.user.js) :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        wikipedia_desktop_redirect
// @namespace   https://jspenguin.org/monkey
// @description Redirect mobile wikipedia to desktop version
// @include     http://*.m.wikipedia.org/*
// @include     https://*.m.wikipedia.org/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var m = /^(https?:\/\/.*)\.m(\.wikipedia\.org\/.*)/.exec(location.href);
if (m) location.href = m[1] + m[2];
```

Comment: Is it secure? This seem to be some type of JavaScript. May it redirect to malicious website?

Comment: Redirector is exactly what I needed, thanks.  I changed `http` to `https` FYI.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: Should be quite secure. AFAIK redirection rules can only be modified by the manual interface.

Comment: I think the forward-slashes need to be escaped for Redirector, too, don't they? Besides, great extension and idea!

Comment: @Biswapriyo : There doesn't seem to be anything here that would allow it to redirect to a malicious website. The namespace directive is only used to avoid name collisions (not to load code).

Comment: The https://jspenguin.org/monkey link is dead, `https://ktpanda.org/monkey/wikipedia_desktop_redirect.user.js` has been suggested as a non-dead alternative link

Answer (score 1):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/skip-mobile-wikipedia/

Here is a Firefox extension if you don't want to use such a big hammer (Redirector) for such a small nail (just mobile Wikipedia links).

Answer (score -3):

Mobile-user-agent extensions will help:

For Firefox: [Mobile View Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mobile-view-switcher/?src=search)

[image: Illustration of switching from desktop to mobile view]

For Chrome: [User-Agent Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg)

Of-course there are several others - you just have to browse the addon-stores!

Comment: This is the opposite of what my question is about.  But it has the side effect of I "only" need to click the extension twice to go from `en.m.wikipedia.org` to `en.wikipedia.org`.  "Only" in the sense that I might as well hand-edit the URL instead.